# How do I check if the user is a site owner in a network?

Tags: multisite, admin, network-admin

I was accidentally using `is_admin()` to check if a user was an admin and found out that function is not checking that. So I looked for another one and I found `is_super_admin()` but that checks if you are a admin of a network of sites or owner of a single WordPress install. I have a network site and I want to know if the user is the owner of the blog. I do not want to use roles. I want to check if the user is the owner of the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar issues with this in the past, WordPress really does need a `is_user_admin()` function.

In the meantime I think the best way to do this is to test if the user has certain capabilities.

```
function is_user_admin(){
    if(!is_super_admin() && current_user_can('activate_plugins'){
        // User is an admin
    }
}
```

Reference:

- [Administrator roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator)
- [`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

Answer (score 2):

The 'activate_plugins' roll only works if superadmin has enabled that privilege in network settings, which they often don't -- it's disabled by default. The proper way is to use the 'administrator' role.

```
if(current_user_can('administrator')) {echo "User is admin!";}
```

See the Summary of Rolls at https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities.